# Error in loading static files in django project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, static

I've created django project and in settings.py configured all the necessary assets

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "~/<project_name>/static",
]
```

I have all of my static files based in the folder `static` in the project directory. Inside this folder I have css, js, images folders accordingly. In my base template (that is inherited by others) called `base.html` I have template tag `{% load staticfiles %}`. I can't figure out why the page still loads without any static attached, because everything seems to be made properly.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this (more in [`STATICFILES_DIRS` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

And inside your templates fetch static files like this (Django 1.10):

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/css-file.css' %}">
```